# React/Redux Test Error: The initialState argument passed to createStore is of unexpected type

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm getting the following error after attempting to run my tests in my react/redux suite. I've ensured that I am using `redux-immutable` as the docs suggest on the repo, to no avail.

```
The initialState argument passed to createStore is of unexpected type. Expected argument to be an instance of Immutable.Collection or Immutable.Record with the following properties:
```

I am using `Immutable.JS()`

## Reducers File:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import budget from '../Budget';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  dashboard,
  budget
});

export default rootReducer;
```

## Store File

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

export function configureStore(){
  // Use redux dev tools if available, otherwise use default composition;
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  const store = createStore(reducers, {}, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  ));

  return store;
}
```

## Attempts

I've tried the following in the `store` file, as a result of me not knowing what the error is, but it still didn't work.

```
  const store = createStore(reducers, Immutable.collection({form: "", dashboard: "", budget: ""}), composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  ));
```

I also tried the following:

https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable

```
  const store = createStore(reducers, Immutable.Map(), composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  ));
```

I tried making a Record immutable object

```
  const StateRecord = Immutable.Record({
    "form": "form",
    "dashboard": "dashboard",
    "budget": "budget"
  });

  const store = createStore(reducers, StateRecord, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  ));
```

Comment: initialState is not defined anywhere in the code you provided. Why don't you try using an empty object? `createStore(reducers, {}, ...)`

Comment: @nbkhope I forgot I added that before to see if I could find a fix. I still get the same error with an empty object.

Comment: @nbkhope Added some new things that I've tried, but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I should have provided my test runner, as it was the source of the problem. Rendering a new provider into my component..

## Test Runner Snippet

```
<Provider store={createStore(reducers, Immutable.fromJS(state))}>
  <ComponentClass {...props} />
</Provider>
```

which orginally looked like

```
<Provider store={createStore(reducers, (state))}>
  <ComponentClass {...props} />
</Provider>
```

Comment: Having the same issue here. What was exactly the solution?